# C# binding failure on missing ".resources" files

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a C# program that links to a (large) third-party library and builds successfully with it. All necessary references between my program and the library are included, and the program starts correctly.

Upon loading the .NET managed DLL for the aforementioned library, I get a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` that says that the library or one of its dependencies could not be loaded ("The specified module could not be found.").

Since the relevant DLL is present in the `Release` directory, I went through the fusion event logs and found only binding failures for a bunch of nonexistent `<PROJECT>.resource.<DLL|EXE>` files under a nonexistent `Release\en` directory. This doesn't make much sense to me at all, since the project's only resource (a single icon) is internalized.

The logs look like this, with some information redacted:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (7/11/2016 @ 10:08:49 AM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Users\USER\Desktop\PROJECT\bin\x86\Release\PROJECT.vshost.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = PROJECT.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/PROJECT/bin/x86/Release/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = PROJECT.vshost.exe
Calling assembly : PROJECT, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\USER\Desktop\PROJECT\bin\x86\Release\PROJECT.vshost.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/PROJECT/bin/x86/Release/en/PROJECT.resources.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/PROJECT/bin/x86/Release/en/PROJECT.resources/PROJECT.resources.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/PROJECT/bin/x86/Release/en/PROJECT.resources.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/PROJECT/bin/x86/Release/en/PROJECT.resources/PROJECT.resources.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

**Update**: This is what Process Monitor shows when loading the DLL:
[image]

The first three loads are the relevant DLL, and the following ones are (ostensibly) its dependencies, all from the standard VS C++ redistributable.

**Update 2**: Dependency Walker shows the same DLLs as missing, although this doesn't seem to manifest at load time:
[image]

Comment: It is probing for a satellite assembly to localize the app to English.  That's entirely normal.

Comment: AFAICT, that's the only binding error. Are you saying that this wouldn't cause the exception/failure I'm seeing?

Comment: "The specified module could not be found" is a Windows error, not a CLR error.  Fuslogvw.exe only traces assembly binds.  If you have no idea what native DLL you are missing then enable loader snaps or use a utility like SysInternals' Process Monitor.

Comment: Procmon doesn't show any missing DLLs or load failures, although it does show the same DLL being loaded three times with different image bases - could that be relevant?